# creating 2 col table with floating divs, clear jQuery for each row

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using floating divs to make a 2 column table structure.
When adding content, the cells should have set clear:left for each row.

I was trying this jQuery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#BokS":even).css("clear","left");
      });
//-->
</script>
```

But it's not working correctly.
Sample page here:
http://www.relasjonskompetanse.no/Boker/Boker.asp
Eg. cell 3 needs clear:left (added manually now)

It could be something very simple I'm forgetting,
but.. can you help out?

Thanks!

Update:

```
<div id="Main2cSC">

    <div class="Prod">
      <div class="SC_Top">Tilpasset ledelse (2015)</div>
      <div class="SC_JS">av Jan Spurkeland</div>
      <a href="/Boker/Relasjonspedagogikk2011.asp"><img src="../images/bok/TILPASSET LEDELSE_w95.png" alt="" name="Prod1" width="94" height="145" class="SC_img" style="border:solid 2px #CCCCCC"></a>
      <div class="SC_Body">
        <p>Tilpasset ledelse er en beskrivelse av hvordan en leder kan møte de fleste menneskers behov for å bli ledet. Stadardisert ledelse treffer ikke noen, mens denne tilnærmingen kan treffe mange. Konseptet erstatter mange historiske forsøk på det samme, mellom annet situasjonsbestemt ledelse.</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p><a class="LesMer" href="http://www.relasjonsledelse.no/default.asp?tekst=bestill">Bestill</a> </p>
      </div>
      <div class="SC_foot"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="Prod">
    repeat..
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: $('#Books:nth-of-type(even)')...

Comment: you can show more html code?

Answer (score 0):

if I am right you want 2 wrapper `<div>`s at `width:50%` and content `<div>`s in that

try:

```
HTML:
<div id="Wrapper">
  <div id="leftCol">
    <div class="contentRow">
      <h2>Left Row 1</h2>
      <p>info ...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contentRow">
      <h2>Left Row 2</h2>
      <p>info ...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="rightCol">
    <div class="contentRow">
      <h2>Right Row 1</h2>
      <p>info ...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

CSS:
#Wrapper{
width: 1000px; /*what ever width you want*/
}
#rightCol, #leftCol{
width:50%
}
.contentRow{
width:100%
}
```

you may want both the right and left `<div>` in some sort of wrapper to help contain them

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
But the actual table-cell-structure is fine.
It's just the odd-div-cell clear:left that I need.
I can do it manually, but thought it would be nice to do with js/jQuery.

Comment: OK, in that case I would need more info to help, such as how the page/tables are being generated etc.

Comment: See updated with html.

BTW: I'll just add manual clear:left for rows now, but I'm glad if I could change as stated above.

Comment: Well after looking the the link again I have had a look at the source and am even more confused. it looks like you are trying to fix a CSS issue with JS.  If all `<div class="Prod">` have `float:left` and they are all 50% width (including boarders and margins) it should be fine.  to make you life easer I would have 2 columns of 50% Width and the rows in that of 100% width.  I will update my solution to show you

Comment: Thanks!
Width is now problem.
<div class="Prod"> do have float:left.
The issue is when an even numbered <div class="Prod"> is less high than the one before. Then next <div class="Prod"> is stacking right, and not left as it's supposed to.

Comment: btw: its's not a css-problem, it's a jQuery/js-problem :)

Comment: then you may want to update the height based on the highest `Prod` and then updating the call with the new height.